# Multi-core JIT in multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.5, multicore, jit

I would like to know about how ProfileOptimization (also known as Multi-core JIT) works in multi-threaded application.

Documentation says that ProfileOptimization tracks and records methods that are called during the application execution. But what if there are multiple threads that are executed at the same time? In this case method call order may differ from run to run. So profile will always be overwritten with the new data.

Does that mean that using Multi-core JIT is not efficient in this scenario? Or may be ProfileOptimization tracks method calls from only the thread that called ProfileOptimazation.StartProfile(...)? Or something else?

Could someone explain how do ProfileOptimization behave in such a case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't very clear why you think threads are a problem, I'll just noodle about the feature for a while.  The traditional way the jitter works is by compiling methods just-in-time, a fraction of a second before the method starts running.  That's different with the multicore JIT option, it necessarily needs to compile methods earlier so it can take advantage of an extra core running the jitter.  Problem is, what method should it compile early?  Clearly there is very little gain if it compiles the wrong one, a method that will only be called minutes from the start of the program.  Or worse, is never called.

To figure out what methods it should work on, it needs to know ahead of time what method will run.  A time machine is not an option of course.  It could only guess at this with some degree of accuracy by knowing what happened *previously*.  With the assumption that, when the program runs for the second time, it will call methods in roughly the same order.

So your call to StartProfile() starts recording the names of the methods that get jitted, simply in the order in which they run for the first time and get compiled.  That list of method names is stored in a file.  Next time you run the program and call StartProfile() again, it now starts using the data in that file to give other cores work to do, pre-compiling the methods in the order in which they appear in the list.

This has pretty decent odds of having the method already compiled before it is runs for the first time, incurring no delay.  Thus improving the warm-start time of your program.  It doesn't have to be, nothing can go wrong when it wasn't compiled yet, the normal just-in-time compilation that traditionally happened takes care of it.  It just isn't as efficient as it *could* be.

If your program is highly non-deterministic when it starts, having wildly different execution paths through the code from one run to the next then, no, the likelihood of multicore jit being a benefit to your startup time is going to be a low one.  The jitter is going to pre-compile the wrong methods.  This is very unusual, real programs rarely behave that way when they start up.  That doesn't otherwise have anything to do with threads, they are not likely to be particularly less deterministic than your main thread.  The opposite actually, the main thread is expected to interact with the user, which can behave irrational like a human can, your workers don't.  And in general a problem with threads, they tend to settle in execution patterns that hide threading race bugs.

Do keep in mind that all of this only matters in the first, give or take, 30 seconds of your program's life.  And only matters to warm-start time.  The jitter simply stops recording completely when the jitting rate drops too low.

Comment: Hans, thank you for very detailed reply. I'll try to clarify my thoughts. Saying that "using Multicore JIT is not efficient" I suggested that it is not so efficient as might be in a single thread environment. Your post confirms this.

Comment: By the way, we are not constrained to use StartProfile() only at the app start up. We can use it any time the application starts doing something for the first time by specifying according profile name in StartProfile(). For example, in our application we use it when we open child windows and it works great. I think it would be also great to use it when starting background tasks, but unfortunately it won't be so efficient because the method call order may be different from one run to the next.